# Line break in TIniFIle in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I easily add a line break
in a TIniFile ?

I'd like to separate each section in the .ini
to make it more readable.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try TMemIniFile? I have a faint recollection that leaves linebreaks between sections.

Comment: @David: it does, but I'm told it also removes any comments.

Comment: @Bruce Yes, that's true. It also works reliably on network shares.

Comment: What's the function to use with TMemIniFile to add a break line ?

Comment: There isn't one. You just save the file and I think that the RTL code adds linebreaks between sections. But I wouldn't stake my life on it.

Comment: TMemIniFile only removes comments starting with a semicolon. Nobody prevents you from using a different commenting style, like //. Yes, that's not commonly used but it works nonetheless.

Comment: I think it might make sense to write your own TMemIniFile-like class if you want something that preserves the entire file layout, including comments and linebreaks

Comment: @warren The question doesn't actually ask to preserve anything, just that when the file is written, sections are nicely separated. The issue of preserving original file comes from other commentors.

Comment: @user382591 The UpdateFile method calls GetStrings which adds the line-break after each section.  Just call UpdateFile.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd clarify the answer of `Wouter van Nifterick`. The current `TIniFile` object in Delphi doesn't support line breaks. To do this, you must do it manually. Here's a sample:

```
procedure LineBreakBeforeSection(const Filename, SectionName: String);
var
  L: TStringList;
  X: Integer;
  S, C: String;
begin
  L:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    L.LoadFromFile(Filename);
    C:= '['+UpperCase(SectionName)+']';
    for X:= 0 to L.Count - 1 do begin
      S:= UpperCase(Trim(L[X]));
      if S = C then begin
        L.Insert(X, '');
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    L.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this one section at a time? Anyway, TMemIniFile is the obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I do that this way:

- open the ini file (as tstringlist.loadfromfile, or tfile.readalllines)
- iterate through all the lines.

  - if the line is not the first line, and the line starts with `[`, then insert a line(break).

As a function that shouldn't take much more work than it was to write this pseudocode.

It's probably the best to wrap this in a tmemini or tinifile descendant so that you don't have to call this manually every time you write to the inifile.